# Insert Average into table from select query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to insert to my table an average of my select query but I am encountering an error

Here is my query:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_average(student_id, first_avg) VALUES 
('100', AVG(SELECT fir_grad FROM tbl_grade 
            WHERE student_id='100' AND school_year='2015-2016'))
```

pls help

Comment: Be wary of storing derived data.

Comment: @Strawberry what do u mean?

Comment: This value can be easily calculated 'on-the-fly', so there's little point storing it in a separate table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use `INSERT INTO SELECT` syntax:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_average(student_id, first_avg) 
SELECT 100, AVG(fir_grad) 
FROM tbl_grade 
WHERE student_id=100 AND school_year='2015-2016'
```

Comment: thaaank you soo much you are a genius
the first one didnt work
but the second one did
I never really tried using INSERT INTO 

PS. this is my first question :)

Comment: @JuanCarlosCabotaje Glad I was able to help and welcome to Stack Overflow. Please mark this, or any other, answer as accepted if it helped you solve your problem.